# React hook unit test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I have the following:

```
const Repairs: React.FC<RepairsProps> = ({repairs, repairsPropertyLoad}) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation()
  const [isARepair, setRepair] = useState(true)
  const handleOnClick = () => { 
    setRepair(false)
    repairsPropertyLoad('token')
  }

  return ( isARepair ? <p>on</p> : <p>off</p> )
  ...
```

since it's also a connected component I have added the following test:

```
describe('Repairs', () => {
  let store: any
  let component: any

  beforeEach(() => {
    store = mockStore({
      repairs: mockRepairs
    })

    store.dispatch = jest.fn()

    component = render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Repairs />
      </Provider>
    )

  })

  it('should render the Repairs component correctly', () => {
    expect(component).toMatchSnapshot()
  })

  it('should find the repair button in the document', () => {
    const { getByText } = component

    const repairsButton = getByText('Repair')
    expect(repairsButton).toBeInTheDocument()
  })
})
```

how can I test the `isARepair` flag scenarios (true and false) so that I can snapshot either `off` or `on` results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would strongly suggest that you write test as if the end user is using your UI. For example, you are setting `setIsRepair` to false when user clicks the button. You can simulate the button click using [`fireEvent`](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-events#fireeventeventname):

```js
fireEvent.click(repairsButton);
expect(getByText('off')).not.toBeNull();
// this might not be the exact code but you get the gist
```

If you want to test your hooks, you should create a custom hook, render it into a dummy test component, and test the return values; or use [React Hooks Testing Library](https://react-hooks-testing-library.com). However, if your state logic is as simple as a single `useState`, I would suggest not testing it because you will essentially be testing React's useState instead of testing a your own state logic. My recommendation is to test state logic that consists of many parts (it is complex enough that it requires a test).